# What is shutter latency in a Phase One medium format camera?

Tags: shutter, medium-format, phase-one

What is shutter latency? The camera I'm using (medium format from Phase One) has the option to set the shutter latency to short or long — what's the difference between the two and when would I use which setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Phase One says the sensor is put to sleep to save battery, and is given a wake-up signal when you press the shutter release button. This wake-up process they call Shutter Latency and recommend to keep it set to "Normal".

The other setting is called "Zero" latency, and suggested to use it only when working with technical large format cameras, or certain manual cameras in special situations. No further explanation about "special situations" but it appears as consuming battery and looks like having the sensor powered up for long times. That would cause the sensor warming up with normal DSLR cameras, but Phase One is different.

I did not read the entire [manual](http://www.phaseone.com/en/SupportMain/Manuals.aspx), so did not find reference to shutter latency settings Long and Short, but only the settings Normal and Zero.

Comment: The reason for going to Zero (and it could have been marked as "short" on older backs) on a view camera is because the back is triggered by the PC X-sync signal from the lens's shutter, which in turn is (usually) a simple mechanical contact that closes when the shutter is completely open. Since the only communication between camera and back is "NOW!!!", there is no time for a wake-up cycle. The same applies with all-mechanical medium format cameras; the only trigger available for the back is the X-sync (M-sync might allow enough time, but we're talking antiques at that point).

Comment: @StanRogers thanks for clarifying zero/normal vs short/long I guess I have an 'older' camera 645AF/P25+

Answer (score 11):

I don't know medium format cameras, but in general shutter latency is the time that it takes from when you push the shutter to the time the shutter actually activates.  The lower the latency, the more responsive the shutter, but the less time the camera has to make last minute adjustments or changes in hardware state.  A higher shutter latency will allow the camera to make finer tuned adjustments and turn on hardware that was sleeping, but will not go as close to when you push the shutter.

Some other cameras express this as shutter priority vs focus priority.  Lower latency should be used when you need the shot at the exact moment you push the shutter where as longer latency will generally let the camera do more work for you or leave stuff powered down and may generate a better quality image or increase battery life.

It may also do things like mirror lockup to reduce the latency so that the shutter can fire faster or keep hardware turned on.

Comment: While ultimately related to shutter latency, focus vs. release priority is mainly an option to disable the actual picture taking (only while autofocus is enabled, generally) if the camera doesn't detect perfect focus on the selected point: the former is usually the default in single action focus, while the latter is most useful with continuous drive and auto-refocusing. Some cameras even have a balanced, intermediate setting.

Comment: And while this answer is correct for the general case (where "shutter latency" and "shutter lag" are synonyms) it does not answer the question that was actually asked, which deals specifically with the shooting modes of medium format backs (in this case, Phase One, but the same settings exist for Leaf and Hasselblad backs as well).

Comment: Might be good to edit the question "What is shutter latency?" to also mention shutter settings in camera menu. I will not do the edit, as with my language skills I'd end up asking something like "what is shuttter latency doing in the kitchen?"

Comment: @EsaPaulasto Your English skills are fine. If you have an improvement to make, go ahead and edit the question and we can clear up any ambiguities after. No problem!

Comment: @mattdm although I am referring specifically to a phase one camera isn't it better to keep things more general? doesn't AJ's answer -answer the (unedited) question? -or does this only apply to medium format?

Comment: @StanRogers - I think the answer still answers it in that the difference is that the camera does more when it is slow.  I didn't mention what the work is because it can differ from one camera to another.  Turning on the sensor from a power downed state still fits as more work.  It may not have an impact on image quality in all cases though.  (That said, I do think that Esa Paulasto's answer is more detailed to the specific case and personally voted it up accordingly.)

Comment: @Pastel  think this question is very different than "what is shutter lag";  even though that's interesting and , but is really different from this specific case. In fact, I think the general answer muddles the issue in this case. I also think it's different from the differences in "shutter priority" vs "focus priority" (which adjusts only one factor in what might or might not be called shutter lag depending on how one defines that term).

Comment: @mattdm so then based on the current question Esa Paulasto's answer is technically more correct? I like the way AJ gave a more general answer -is it incorrect?

Comment: @Pastel if you are considering which one to give the answer to, I personally would go with Esa's.  I agree with MattDM and StanRoders that it is a more detailed answer to the particular question being asked.  I think my answer will be useful to people as well, but they will also see both answers when they come here.

Comment: thanx for making my decision easier, i was finding it difficult to decide because i am not familiar with the things i asked about

Comment: @Pastel this question is about the menu settings. When we talk about shutter latency ([shutter lag examples](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/35876/17441)) we usually mean a time from shutter release to image capture. The point being: shutter lag _is time_. Here in your question the shutter latency _is a setting in camera menu_. That's the difference :)